# What is the difference between QueryTask and featureLayer.queryFeatures

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query-task

For fetching data from a feature layer, I've been using QueryTask service,

```
    var deferred = new Deferred();
    var queryTask = new QueryTask(featureLayerurl)
    var query = new Query();
     query.geometry = geometry;        
    query.where = "document='100'";
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    query.outFields = ["*"];

    return deferred = queryTask.execute(query).addErrback(function (response) {
        console.error(response);
        return null;
    }).addCallback(function (response) {
        return response;
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response;
    });
```

But recently, I've found that there is dedicated method in **FeatureLayer** class called **queryFeatures** for for fetching data.

```
var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
query.objectIds = [features[0].attributes.OBJECTID];
query.outFields = [ "*" ];
// Query for the features with the given object ID
featureLayer.queryFeatures(query, function(featureSet) {
});
```

So ,

1. Is there any difference between when using QueryTask over
   queryFeatures?
2. Any  kind a of performance difference ?
3. Do queryFeautres is using QueryTask internally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your three questions:

1. Yes.
2. Yes (for most use cases).
3. No.

QueryTask is the older/original way - available since the initial version 1.0 and originally the only way. At version 2.0, FeatureLayer was added. This removed the need for using the QueryTask+GraphicsLayer combo in many use cases.  There still a few valid use cases for it, but in general you're better off using the FeatureLayer (and its queryFeatures() method).
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#queryfeatures

Comment: What you mean by original way, could you please explain?

Comment: With "original", I mean "from the beginning".  QueryTask was part of the original/first version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, version 1.0, which was released in 2008. While FeatureLayer was introduced at version 2.0 (in 2010).
https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/07/09/the-arcgis-javascript-api-is-now-available-to-the-public/ 
https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/06/29/arcgis-apis-for-javascript-and-flex-version-2-0-now-final/

Comment: Okay , thanks , one more question, by  'This removed the need for using the QueryTask+GraphicsLayer combo ' means ?